# how can i access a vector of pointers pointing to other vectors? I tried the hackerrank program variable sized arrays in c++:

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

> Consider an n-element array a, , where each index i in the array
> contains a reference to an array of k(i) integers (where the value of
> k(i)  varies from array to array).
>
> Given a , you must answer q queries. Each query is in the format i j,
> where  denotes an index in array a and j denotes an index in the array
> located at a[i]. For each query, find and print the value of element j
> in the array at location a[i]  on a new line.

```
int n,q,k,input,r,s;
cin>>n>>q;
vector<int*> a;
vector<int> vec;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   
    cin>>k;
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        cin>>input;
        vec.push_back(input);
    }
    a.push_back(vec.data());
}
for(int m=0;m<q;m++)
{
    cin>>r>>s;
    cout<<endl<<*(a[r]+s);
    
}
```

Comment: I assume that your question is "why does this seemingly valid code crash?" but you haven't said what your question is

Comment: With a bit of effort, that could be three-stars-programmer grade.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I was asking that only. I just posted the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chief problem here is that each member of `a` should point to a **different** array. That's at least what the exercise suggests. You make all elements of `a` point to the **same** `vec` vector.

There's also the slight matter that `vec.data()` keeps changing as it grows, but that's probably solved when you fix that first problem.

Note that in C++, we'd typically use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for this problem. The literal interpretation "each index i in the array contains a *reference*" wouldn't work because a C++ reference can't be a member of a vector, but the exercise does not appear to written with C++ in mind. Hence, "reference" does not mean C++ reference.